# JS functions composed in the opposite order

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, function-composition

Starting with a simple function composition

```
const fa = (x => (x + "a"));
const fb = (x => (x + "b"));
fb(fa('x'))
```

I played around and I obtained the following code snippet which returns 'xba' instead of 'xab'.

Can someone explain why?

```js
const fa = next => x => next(x + "a");
const fb = next => x => next(x + "b");

console.log(fb(fa(y => y))('x'));
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I expected 'xab'. But I don't know what is the order of execution or what exactly is happening.
So I would like to understand why 'xba' is the resutl

Comment: `fa` creates a function that appends `"a"`. This function is passed to `fb`, which appends `"b"`, then calls the passed function (which appends `"a"`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's break this down:

```
const _fa = fa(y => y)
// _fa = x => (y => y)(x + "a")
```

To avoid confusing the two `x` let's name it as `x1`

```
// _fa = x1 => (y => y)(x1 + "a")
```

Now `fb` would be:

```
// fb = next => x2 => next(x2 + "b")
```

If we call `fb` with `fa(y => y)` (ie. `_fa`), we substitute `next` with `_fa`:

```
_fb = fb(fa(y => y))
// _fb = x2 => (x1 => (y => y)(x1 + "a"))(x2 + "b")
```

Now lets evaluate `_fb` with the argument `x2 = 'x'`:

```
// _fb = (x1 => (y => y)(x1 + "a"))("x" + "b")
// _fb = (x1 => (y => y)(x1 + "a"))("xb")
```

Notice how `x1 => (y => y)(x1 + "a")` can be simplified to `x1 => x1 + "a"`. Now we have:

```
// _fb = (x1 => x1 + "a")("xb")
```

Now let's evaluate this function `(x1 => x1 + "a")` with argument `x1 = "xb"`

```
// _fb = "xb" + "a"
// _fb = "xba"
```

Answer (score 1):

You might not know it, but you're looking at the continuation monad! Also the [thrush combinator](http://www.angelfire.com/tx4/cus/combinator/birds.html).

```js
const Cont = someValue => next =>
  next (someValue)

const fa = x =>
  Cont (x + "a")

const fb = x =>
  Cont (x + "b")

fa ("x") (fb) (console.log)
// xab

fb ("x") (fa) (console.log)
// xba

fa ("x") (fa) (fa) (fa) (fb) (console.log)
// xaaaab

fb ("x") (fa) (fb) (fa) (fb) (console.log)
// xbabab
```

In a slightly more involved example, we illustrate `liftA2` which takes a binary function and "lifts" it into our `Cont` context. Now we can take two `Cont` values and use them with any ordinary function.

```js
const Cont = someValue => next =>
  next (someValue)
  
const liftA2 = f => mx => my =>
  mx (x =>
    my (y =>
      Cont (f (x, y))))

const mult = (x, y) =>
  x * y
  
const main =
  liftA2 (mult) (Cont (6)) (Cont (7))
  
main (console.log)
// 42

main (x => Cont (x + 1)) (console.log)
// 43
```